# Backstage - Create plugin from template gives publisher error

Tags: templates, github, backstage

I am trying to develop a simple plugin on Backstage for the first time. I thought I installed and configured everything right

```
Unable to find a publisher for URL: https://github.com/my_name/my_repo. Please make sure to register this host under an integration in app-config
```

So, the repo exist, my github token is in the `.env` file, `the app-config.yaml` is the default one, where github, gitlab, bitbucket and azure are already present and configured in the `integrations` section.

The weird thing is that the error happens in `plugins/scaffolder-backend/src/scaffolder/stages/publish/publishers.ts`, and if I try to print `this.publisherMap`, only bitbucket.org is present in the map. Somehow, it doesn't load gitlab, github or whatever.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by running the backend like this:

```
sudo GITHUB_TOKEN=<token> yarn start
```